# Microsoft Word macro to count comments

Tags: vba, windows, ms-word, ms-office

I work as an instructional designer; I work on editing word documents by adding comments. I was asking if I can find a Word macro that helps me in counting these comments and classifying them.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `Sub` to count items according to your categories:

```
Sub CountComments()
    Dim spelling, grammar, rephrasing, technical, other As Integer
    spelling = 0
    grammar = 0
    rephrasing = 0
    technical = 0
    other = 0

    Dim comment As comment
    For Each comment In ActiveDocument.Comments

        Dim firstWord As String
        firstWord = Split(comment.Range.Text, " ")(0)

        Select Case LCase(firstWord)
            Case "spelling"
                spelling = spelling + 1
            Case "grammar"
                grammar = grammar + 1
            Case "rephrasing"
                rephrasing = rephrasing + 1
            Case "technical"
                technical = technical + 1
            Case Else
                other = other + 1
        End Select
    Next

    MsgBox _
        "Spelling:" & spelling & _
        "; Grammar:" & grammar & _
        "; Rephrasing:" & rephrasing & _
        "; Technical:" & technical & _
        "; Other:" & other, , "Comment category summary"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Simon for your comment; I am wondering if I can filter these comments and classify them into categories. For example, we've 4 types of errors (spelling, grammatical, rephrasing and technical), and I write the type of error as the first word of the comment. I need a macro to count the number of incidents per type of error to use it in evaluation issues instead of manually counting them. Appreciate your reply.

Comment: @user1603146, I've updated to show you an approach to your categorisation problem.